# Использование "я" и "мне"

Tags: выбор-слова

I'm having difficulty understanding when to use "Я" and when to use "мне".  In the sentence:

> Я хочу книгу

We use "Я" meaning `I`.  But in the sentence:

> Мне нужна книга

We use "Мне" meaning `I`.  Why don't we use "Я"?

Comment: By the way, usage translates as "использование". But barring the soft ль sound, you almost captured the typical pronunciation here.

Comment: While you can use "I" here, "Я нуждаюсь в [этой] книге", it just sounds odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to note what the subject of the sentence is. In `Мне нужна книга` the subject is, actually, `книга`. Hence, `книга` is in the nominative case, and `мне` is in the dative case. The subject is the thing that is necessary, and not the person to whom it is necessary.

In Russian you see such forms quite often.  Consider this:

> Мне нравится эта книга.
>
> I like this book.

Same idea: in the Russian sentence the book is the subject.

Comment: понял сейчас!  спасибо! ;)

Comment: Actually Spanish has the same construction as English: Necesito un libro.

Comment: @CocoPop, you mean the same as Russian, right?  Because  "un libro" is the subject.

Comment: No, libro is the direct object of necesitar: ¿Necesito qué? -un libro.

Comment: Are you sure? But "Necesito" agrees with "un libro" in gender...  In Russian, the verb has to agree with the subject, not the object, so I assumed the same would be true in Spanish.

Comment: The -o in necesito is the present ending for the 1st person. Note: Necesito una amiga. Necesitas un libro.

Comment: Ok. Bad example. Removed.

Answer (score 6):

**Мне** actually means "to me" and is in the dative case, whereas **я** means "I" and is in the nominative case.

To review:

The nominative is the case of the subject of the sentence. In this case **я**: 
The accusative is the case of the direct object - in this case книга ➝ **книгу**.

> **Я** хочу книгу.

The dative is the case of the indirect object, i.e. the recipient - in this case я ➝ **мне**:

> **Мне** нужна книга. (literally: to me (is) necessary (a) book)

Comment: that's interesting.. i'll have to study this...

Answer (score 4):

The reason behind the inversion in your second example is that *нужна* is not a verb (*need*). It is a modal predicative construction similar to adjective. So, in English it would be close to *a book is necessary to me*. And *to me* is *мне*.

In practice you need to know these constructions by heart, but I guess identifying the parts of speech would help.

Answer (score 1):

Once again, don't have the rep to add a comment to @CocoPop answer, this is only meant as an addition to what's already said:

> Я хочу книгу.
>
> I want a book.

or

> Мне нужна книга.
>
> I need a book ( literally: [Myself | to me] needs [a] book )

or

> Я нуждюсь в книге.
>
> I am in need of a book.

Comment: "Мне нужна книга" is more like "To me is needed a book." Книга is the subject here.